# Under the input box form labels

Tags: css, html

I am looking for help.  I cannot find out how to get my code to allow form labels to appear under my form input see this example of a picture demonstrating what I am looking for: [example](http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/top-aligned.png).

Like first, last, MM, DD, YYYY, ### from the example.  Everything I can find is for over the input box labels or off to the side labels.

Can someone provide some code to help me duplicate the under the input box code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input_cont">
<input type="text" class="inp" id="first" name="first">
<label for="first" class="lbl">I'm first</label>
</div><div class="input_cont">
<input type="text" class="inp" id="second" name="second">
<label for="second" class="lbl">I'm second</label></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input,label{margin:0;}
.inp{display:block;}
.lbl{font-size:9pt; color:#999}
.input_cont{display:inline-block; zoom:1; *display:inline; margin-right:10px}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KxnCv/